# which bash command is good for extracting multiple pattern from text file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have very big text file and just need to extract some specific patterns from it and save in other .txt file.

Here is the format of my text file:

```
"1","Dbxref=Entrez%7CGene:5008779;ID=GSPATG00000003001;Name=GSPATG00000003001;Ontology_term=GO:0005488"
"2","Dbxref=Entrez%7CProtein:XP_001422966,EMBL:CAK55568,Uniprot:A0BAK1_PARTE,Entrez%7CProtein:124390026;Derived_from=GSPATT00000003001;ID=GSPATP00000003001;isoelectric_point=10.31;molecular_weight=55095.3;Name=GSPATP00000003001;Ontology_term=GO:0005488"
"3","Alias=PTMB.459;Dbxref=Entrez%7CGene:5008781,Entrez%7CNucleotide:CR548612;ID=GSPATG00000005001;Name=GSPATG00000005001;Ontology_term=GO:0004185,GO:0006508"
"4","Dbxref=Entrez%7CProtein:XP_001422968,Entrez%7CProtein:124390028,EMBL:CAK55570,Uniprot:Q6BFB1_PARTE;Derived_from=GSPATT00000005001;ID=GSPATP00000005001;isoelectric_point=6.41;molecular_weight=48434.5;Name=GSPATP00000005001;Ontology_term=GO:0004185,GO:0006508"
"5","Alias=PTMB.456;Dbxref=Entrez%7CNucleotide:CR548612,Entrez%7CGene:5008770;ID=GSPATG00000009001;Name=GSPATG00000009001;Ontology_term=GO:0004672,GO:0004674,GO:0004713,GO:0005524,GO:0006468"
"6","Dbxref=Entrez%7CProtein:XP_001422972,Entrez%7CProtein:124390032,EMBL:CAK55574,Uniprot:Q6BFB4_PARTE;Derived_from=GSPATT00000009001;ID=GSPATP00000009001;isoelectric_point=9.79;molecular_weight=73346.4;Name=GSPATP00000009001;Ontology_term=GO:0004672,GO:0004674,GO:0004713,GO:0005524,GO:0006468"
"7","Dbxref=Entrez%7CGene:5008748;ID=GSPATG00000010001;Name=GSPATG00000010001;Ontology_term=GO:0005515,GO:0007154,GO:0035091"
```

What I need, I just need to extract all the words for : 
`ID, Name and Ontology_term` . 
for example the expected output for the line 7 would be :

```
ID=GSPATG00000010001;Name=GSPATG00000010001;Ontology_term=GO:0005515,GO:0007154,GO:0035091"
```

How can I do it in Linux terminal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/.*;\(ID[^;]*\).*;\(Name[^;]*\).*;\(Ontology_term[^;]*\).*/\1;\2;\3/' file
ID=GSPATG00000003001;Name=GSPATG00000003001;Ontology_term=GO:0005488"
ID=GSPATP00000003001;Name=GSPATP00000003001;Ontology_term=GO:0005488"
ID=GSPATG00000005001;Name=GSPATG00000005001;Ontology_term=GO:0004185,GO:0006508"
ID=GSPATP00000005001;Name=GSPATP00000005001;Ontology_term=GO:0004185,GO:0006508"
ID=GSPATG00000009001;Name=GSPATG00000009001;Ontology_term=GO:0004672,GO:0004674,GO:0004713,GO:0005524,GO:0006468"
ID=GSPATP00000009001;Name=GSPATP00000009001;Ontology_term=GO:0004672,GO:0004674,GO:0004713,GO:0005524,GO:0006468"
ID=GSPATG00000010001;Name=GSPATG00000010001;Ontology_term=GO:0005515,GO:0007154,GO:0035091"
```

`[^;]*` matches any character but not of a semicolon zero or more times. In basic sed, capturing groups are referred by `\(..\)` .

Comment: thanks. seems nice solution. How can I change this command such that, only the terms after Name and Ontology_term  remain and all other deleted? for example for the last line : GSPATG00000010001, GO:0005515,GO:0007154,GO:0035091"

Comment: try this `sed 's/.*;Name=\([^;]*\).*;Ontology_term=\([^;]*\).*/\1;\2/' file` . [Accept if this answer works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your input format is pesky in that it contains semicolon-separated fields inside a double-quoted comma-separated field.  If we can be sure that the first field before the first semicolon is always uninteresting and that the last field should also always be discarded, we can cheat by simply splitting on semicolons and extract the fields we want.

```
awk -F ';' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { sub(/"$/, "", $i);
  if ($i ~ /^(ID|Name|Ontology_term)=/) printf "%s", $i; printf "\n" } }' file
```

If these assumptions do not always hold, maybe you can massage or preprocess the input so they do.  In fact, I do this by trimming any final double-quote.  Ultimately, parsing the input and translating it to a well-defined flat comma- or semicolon-separated format (or JSON if you have a lot of optional fields or nested structures) might be the most robust and fruitful solution.